# Web Api Versioning using Header , How can we use it on Swagger UI using Net Framework MVC Api

Tags: api, swagger, versioning, webapi, aspnet-api-versioning

Hi I have been using the header versioning method in my API, below is the link.
My problem now is i cant seem to work it with the Swagger in SwaggerConfig.cs

I will show you the code in Multiple Versioning but it doesnt work. this is the part of multi versioning

```
  public class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                { c.MultipleApiVersions(
                        (apiDesc, targetApiVersion) => targetApiVersion.Equals("V1", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||                     // Include everything by default
                              apiDesc.Route.RouteTemplate.StartsWith(targetApiVersion, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase), // Only include matching routes for other versions
                         (vc) =>
                        {
                            vc.Version("V1", "Real Time API V1");
                            vc.Version("V2", "Real Time API V2");
                        });  }) .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                { c.EnableDiscoveryUrlSelector();});
```

https://seroter.com/2012/09/25/versioning-asp-net-web-api-services-using-http-headers/

The Header APi is working with Different Controller with the SAME api Route..
so my versioning is all about in controller name basis.. Can some one help me.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in a pretty simple and straight forward way with [ASP.NET API Versioning](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning). You can easily version by any method you want, including by header. To integrate with an OpenAPI/Swagger generator, such as Swashbuckle, you need only add the API Explorer extensions which are API version-aware. You can review an end-to-end [Web API example here](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/tree/master/samples/webapi/SwaggerWebApiSample).

> Disclaimer: I am the owner and author

The method you are showing appears to be some alternate form of versioning that I'm not familiar with. I can say from experience that the **Try It!** feature can be tricky when you version by header and things are cross-origin. This has to do with how CORS works. The browser will **not** send custom headers in the preflight, which would include the API version header. In order to get around that, I *believe* there is a hook in the Swagger UI/JavaScript where you can manually inject the header just before the CORS request is made.